# "Конь не валялся"

Tags: фразеология

Когда говорят о несделанной работе, то выражаются, что там еще "конь не валялся". Интересно было бы узнать происхождение этой поговорки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Изначально - о нетронутых пастбищах и целинных землях, куда еще не выводили лошадей. И обязательно с "там": "Там еще конь не ваялся".
Мне кажется, что это объяснение самодостаточно, дальнейшее только путает. 
Еще, правда, ссылаются на некий обычай "не начинать работ, пока конь не повалялся". Никаких подробностей при этом не сообщают, но само утвеждение, что конь может валяться **перед работой**, а не на отдыхе или по причине болезни, кажется странноватым.

Врочем, скопипасчу без комментариев один текст, где много интересных сведений, хотя мало объяснений происхождения выражения.

---

оказывается, этимология выражения "и конь не валялся" доподлинно неизвестна. существуют лишь несколько версий и бесконечные споры специалистов.

1) поговорка отражает русский крестьянский обычай давать лошади поваляться перед тем, как ее запрягать, - чтобы она меньше уставала во время работы.

2) происхождение оборота связано с повадкой лошадей валяться перед тем, как дать надеть на себя хомут или седло, что задерживало работу.

3) самая короткая - ассоциативная версия. Конь не валялся – значит, трава не примята. Поляна не топтана, цветы не сорваны.

4) А вот и версия Н. Вашкевича: 
"Смысл выражения "конь не валялся" таков: работа еще и не начиналась, т.е. ничего еще не сделано. Как такой конкретный смысл, зафиксированный в словарях, вдруг вытекает из двух понятий "конь" и "валялся"? Во всех таких случаях мы читаем по-арабски, смотрим арабскими глазами: "конь" - при беглом произношении звучит "кн" (означает "как-будто"), а "валяться"- это арабский глагол "валле" (означает "приняться за работу"). Остается только русское отрицание, получаем: "еще за работу не принялись", "еще ничего не сделано", что точно соответствует словарному значению."

5) Припомнив мифы, натолкнули на мысль посмотреть у Фрезера. 
Оказывается, в Европе существовала традиция отождествления хлеба (зерна) с лошадью (или с другими животными). (следовательно "не валялся" - "не посеян"?? прим. tanoshii)

6) 1. Лошадь для земледельца Твери или Лилля -- важная тягловая сила. 
2. Особенностью физиологии Л. является ее практически уникальная способность к неконтролируемой лошадиным организмом анаэробной работе. Поэтому существует постоянный риск перегрузки Л. При небольшой перегрузке она ложится, при чрезмерной -- падает и погибает. 
3. Труд крестьянина наших геграфических широт всегда был в страду чрезвычайно напряженным, день кормил год. Так что работа и хозяина, и его двигателя была или до упаду, или чуть ли не до упаду. Работа заканчивалась тем, что оба валились с ног. Для хозяина это было не опасно, для лошади -- напротив, могло стать концом, важно было знать и чувствовать этот предел.  
Так что свалиться, валяться -- нормальный признак конца работы, он, естественно, должен был найти отражение и в лексике. 
"У нас конь валялся!" -- Это означало, что мы хорошо поработали. 
4. От банального выражения до его переосмысления, причем иронического -- один шаг. В языке такие шаги случаются часто и густо. Свойство ли это нашего путанного сознания-новодела, признак ли накопления в языке экстраклеточной генетической информации -- неизвестно. Но сам факт неоспорим.

7) А еще по тому, как конь валяется, наши предки определяли, много ли за него можно выручить: если лошадь катается по земле и перевернется на спину, значит, хозяин продаст ее с барышом, а если нет – то с убытком.

8) С другой стороны, есть у русских поверье, вошедшее в словарь В.Даля: «Знать, там и умереть, где конь валялся». Что-то похожее есть и у украинцев: по их представлениям, походив по тому месту, где валялся конь, можно подхватить лишай – связаться с воплощенной в коне «нечистой силой». В.Мокиенко в книге «Почему так говорят?» посвящает «валянию коня» целую главу и вспоминает, как в Юрьев день, «конский праздник», лошадям обязательно давали поваляться в утренней росе по ниве «для здоровья».

9) Русский валенок начинал валяться с кона - мыска. "Еще кон не валялся", т.е. до окончания работы над валенком еще очень далеко.

10) на сайте любителей лошадей написано, что кони валяются, когда их пучит. Места, где они валяются, внимательно изучают, чтобы выяснить, есть ли у них колики в животе и надо ли принимать меры.

11) в русском языке два слова - "конец" и "начало" фактически однокоренные. Древнерусское конъ (конь) означало предел, начало, конец, а выражение "от кона до кона" -- "с начала до конца". 
Если к моменту появления поговорки "и конь не валялся" народ не забыл эту подробность, то логично допустить возможность образного переосмысления кона и коня

---

http://otvet.mail.ru/question/30182863

Comment: Вашкевич этот очень похож на лингвофрика с такой аргументацией.

Answer (score 4):

На [Грамоте](http://www.gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/nauka_i_zhizn/28_762) есть про этого коня:

> ...
>   Никогда на Руси (равно как и в других краях) перед работой коней не валяли...
>   Зато в нашей стране в больших количествах валялись валенки. 
>   Валенок начинают валять не с носка (который, кстати, никто и никогда не называл «коном»), не с пятки и не с голенища. И на фабриках, и в частных мастерских каждый валенок валяется сразу — целиком...
>   Изготовлению собственно валенка предшествует валяние войлока — заготовки, основы будущей обуви. А согласно словарю Владимира Даля, в старину понятия «начало», «основа» передавались почти забытым в настоящее время словом «кон». Отсюда — исконный (изначальный), испокон веку (то есть от начала времён).
>   Валяние основы — начало всего дела. Если «ещё и кон не валялся», значит, мастер и не приступал к работе.
>   А каким образом «кон» превратился в «конь»? Слово «кон» обозначало любое начало, а не только начало изготовления валенка. Очевидно, со временем связь крылатого выражения именно с этой работой утратилась, да и слово «кон» вышло из разряда общеупотребительных. А поговорка уже прижилась. И при быстром произнесении «кон не валялся» («конневалялся») звук [н] непроизвольно смягчается. Так с течением времени и возникла загадка: валяющийся перед началом работы конь.

Comment: Это не "на грамоте", а личное мнение одного  далекого от этимологии, но с развитой фантазией автора, на которое грамота дала ссылку. Кстати, уже убрали эту ссылку.

Comment: Первоисточник: http://www.nkj.ru/archive/articles/26452/index.php?PAGEN_3=2&ELEMENT_ID=26452#nav_start_3

Answer (score 0):

Когда русские строили дом или дома на новом месте, то выпускали лошадей и следили за тем, куда лошадь ляжет отдыхать. Выбранное животными место (или места) считалось хорошим и для человека, и это действительно так. Отсюда и поговорка пошла.

Comment: И как это со смыслом «поговорки» стыкуется? Или смысл у неё иной?

Answer (score 0):

Конь знает, что его запрягут в хомут на весь день и испачкаться в грязи в оглоблях не получится. А грязь из лужи – это самая лучшая защита от насекомых. Поэтому хозяин позволял своей животине сначала создать броню на коже, а потом только запрягал.
Отсюда – о неначатой работе – так и говорили: конь не валялся.

Comment: Наверное, труд лужекопа с той поры и стал почётным.

Answer (score 0):

Кон — это цикл карточной игры... впрочем и любой другой игры со ставками.
Все мы знаем: Сделать ставку — поставить на кон
Валять кон — раскидывать игральные карты в начале игры (раздать карты).
А при чем тут кони и крестьяне?
Да вообще ни при чем.
Просто не всем понятный кон превратился в коня.

Comment: Хотелось бы хоть какую-то аргументацию...

Comment: Кон — слово знакомое не только картёжникам. С каких пор он стал «не всем понятный»?

Comment: Уж не знаю какие такие аргументы вам еще надо, просто лично мне это слово знакомо с детства.